# What's Your Method of not forgetting the end brackets, parentheses

Tags: coding-style, efficiency, methodology

*disclaimer: for simplicity sake, brackets will refer to brackets, braces, quotes, and parentheses in the couse of this question. Carry on.*

When writing code, I usually type the beginning and end element first, and then go back and type the inner stuff. This gets to be a lot of backspacing, especially when doing something with many nested elements like:

```
jQuery(function($){$('#element[input="file"]').hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut();}));
```

Is there a more efficient way of remembering how many brackets you've got open ?

Or a second example with quotes:

```
<?php echo '<input value="'.$_POST['name'].'" />"; ?>
```

Comment: Let the IDE automatically put in the "ending" token when I type the "opening" one...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I start out like this `{}`, then usually fill them with something. Whenever you type `{`, type a corresponding `}` and stick it on a new line. The worst thing you have to do in that case is fix indentation prior to committing.

*Good* syntax highlighters will often alert you to a problem, but not always. My preferred editor KATE, for instance, choked on a JSON formatted 'printf style' variadic argument string.

Don't trust bracket and paren highlighting! Always close what you open immediately after opening it and *then* fill in the gaps.

Comment: +1 For pointing out the fallibility of paren-matching, particularly with variadic functions and I find, mixed-mode code.

Comment: @Tim So you might write {} and then backspace and fill in {()} and _then_ put the contents in?

Comment: @JMC Creative - yes, almost always. If I open { or ( or even [, I close it on another line and the indent it accordingly. If I open too many, to the point that I indent more than three / four tab levels deep, I re-think what I'm doing.

Comment: @Tim Post: Good point. Deep nesting in expressions is as much of an indicator of need for refactoring as deep nesting in control structures. Also, a lot of IDEs have an option to automatically add the closing delimiter after the cursor whenever you type an opener. I could never quite get used to it, though, and occasionally it got in my way, so I do this, too, instead.

Comment: @Jon I never found an IDE that didn't get in my way. I just use simple text editors and practices that have saved me time.

Comment: @Tim Post: I can't fault you for that. The only features I really use in my IDE are syntax highlighting, autocompletion, project management, and keybindings for compilation and execution, all of which are well within the capabilities of a decent text editor.

Comment: @Jon, what, no code folding? (ducks)

Comment: @Tim Post: Uh, no? :does not strike: I don't use it. It's easier for me to be able to see everything at once, and just put related code in close proximity.

Comment: @Tim, @Jon - I used to love code folding, but that was in the days of GFA Basic. For imperative code, these days, I say no - your functions shouldn't often be long enough to benefit. In a language like C# or Java, where method implementations cannot easily be given separately from the class, I think there's a good reason for it. Beyond that, find and bookmarks give me all the easy navigation in large files I need.

Answer (score 34):

**Indentation**

One-liners like that do introduce a bit of a hazard in terms of keeping the brackets correctly matched.  Most decent editors will match the brackets visually to help, but it is easier to expand it.

```
(function($) {
    $('#element[input="file"]').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note your example was incorrectly matched.

Comment: That's why python is great, it forces you to indent and all the programs look similar.

Comment: "incorrectly matched" .. Oh, I just did that to prove my point.  :)

Comment: @JMC Creative: Thought you may well have done. ;-)

Comment: @Will: Forcing you to adopt a particular style of indentation (and an inconsistent one at that) does not make a language _great_.

Comment: @Josh K  yes it does.  http://xkcd.com/353/

Comment: @Will: A XKCD comic (while awesome) is not evidence to a language's benefits. I love Python, but if I could change one thing it would be the indentation scope.

Comment: @Josh K: Haskell uses indentation like that as well, is it better there, or always bad?

Comment: @Orbling: I have barely begun to look at Haskell, much less be able to tell if it's good or not.

Comment: @Josh K: Righto. I always found it clean, but can be annoying if you use real tabs rather than spaces.

Comment: @Orbling: I can tell I think Haskell is interesting (functional, strict) however if it does use the same block indentation then I would be disappointed.

Comment: @Josh K: It does use spacing, but the code style is so different the feel of it and purpose is somewhat different.  You'll experience it at some point I'm sure.  It's a good language to learn.

Comment: @Orbling: I'm looking at [Snap](http://snapframework.com/) since I'm most familiar with some sort of web based development (though did a lot of Java as well). Anything else you recommend for learning?

Comment: Haskell's whitespace thing doesn't seem intrusive, to this newbie at least. Mostly `haskell-mode` just does whatever it does; I only became aware that there was an actual whitespace syntax (some things have to line up vertically) accidentally, while reading some tutorial or other.

Comment: Oh, and LYAH rocks, for a complete newbie: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: @Frank: That looks great, I appreciate the link.

Comment: @Frank Shearer: As in emacs `haskell-mode`? ;-)

Comment: @Josh K: Ooh, never used Snap - will look in to that.  So many things are worth learning it's very hard to list anything in particular.  From a career perspective, most interfaces seem to be moving to the web and most web-interfaces seem to be getting entirely dynamic, so I think jQuery (as the dominant client-side framework) is becoming very useful.  Particularly as it has a very fluid functional style within javascript, so it exposes the functional paradigm nicely - which is gaining great traction at long last.

Comment: @Orbling :) I did try get `SHIME` working, and then got stuck and was distracted by something else. I'd like to give it another go at some stage.

Comment: @Frank Shearar: Never used it myself, though it looks awesome, `haskell-mode` always sufficed (although I used to use `hugs-mode` mainly)!  I never get tired of looking at elisp code when done well, looks so pretty: https://github.com/chrisdone/shime/blob/master/shime.el

Comment: @Orbling: I've done a lot of JavaScript (and jQuery) and that's mainly what turned me on to other functional programming languages. I like Haskell because it's strongly typed, something I miss from JAva in other languages.

Comment: @Josh K: Well the benefits of strong-typing do show themselves nicely in Haskell.  I've been working in non-typed languages for such a long time now, I tend to find typing a bit of an inconvenience.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I type an opening brace, my editor (Visual Studio with Visual Assist) inserts the closing one for me.  Much easier...

Comment: Mine, Komodo Edit, does as well.  That plus bracket-matching makes it a non-issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use a text editor that highlights matched parens as you type. A certain amount of count along the line, +1 for open, -1 for close, check you end back at zero will happen at some point, but very rarely if you have a good text editor.

Some command-line prompts probably do similar matched-paren-highlighting if you configure them for it, though my quick bash-in-konsole experiment didn't seem to do it by default.

In the past, I used to type each matched pair at once, then cursor back over the closing paren. Still do out of habit quite a bit. This sounds like what you describe, but there's no backspacing, only cursor-left into the parens, and cursor-right to escape back out.

Comment: I find a lot of editors default to inserting the matching paren/quote for you, often with some sort of automatic overwrite when typing the bracket after the content.  If typing a long one-liner, then pre-typing the closing bracket is *definitely* a good idea.

Comment: If it types the closing bracket for me, I turn that off. Typing is too much a habit/reflex thing. With that option on, I'd end up with lots of duplicated brackets making a complete mess of my code for about 10 mins, then I'd probably smash the monitor with the keyboard.

Comment: Me too.  I end up in a right mess with automatic insertion switched on if I'm not paying enough attention.  I'm not very pro my computer doing anything with my caret/focus automatically - I type fast, and flipping about with that causes consternation!

Answer (score 2):

When i use an editor that does not close my braces/parenthesis automatically I create them both at the same time. Then move them to their ending location. This is convienent when you have a coding pattern that you have settled into. Even if your one lining it, creating opening and closing brackets at the same time wont hurt. I use the same practice with JavaScript, C#, and Ruby. Try it.

e.g.

Step 1

```
if(true)
```

Step 2

```
if(true){}
```

Step 3

```
if(true)
{
    //Put your code here
}
```

Comment: Argh at GNU style braces, and no space after if!

Comment: I believe GNU indents the braces by two?

Answer (score 2):

I almost never forget to close my braces. I guess there is a mixture at work.

- I code in small pieces. I try to avoid methods longer than a screen. Use submethods instead.
- Indentation helps, if I'm not sure, whether I have to close something
- compiling. Yes - I use a language which warns me if I forgot a brace. But I get warnings seldom.

Answer (score 1):

An editor with good syntax highlighting helps a lot.

I use Vim, for example, which by default (since 7.0, I think) highlights the matching paren/brace/bracket as you type or when the cursor is on one of them. It even highlights as an error when there are unmatched pairs.

If your editor does not do this, it is doing you a disservice. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I miss it, the compiler will catch it.  It's usually no big deal.

Comment: I've seen compilers spit out a huge load of junk from a missing parentheses or bracket, which took me hours to get to the bottom of the mess (caused errors in a later included file rather than the header the error was in). Prevention is the best cure in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason I like non-C-type languages such as VB and Ruby, since they don't use curly brackets to mark blocks, or semicolons to end lines.

I know people tend to slag VB as "verbose", but I actually like the keywords it uses since the meaning is abundantly clear. I mean, it's easier to distinguish an "End If" line than it is to figure out if this curly brace ends a conditional, or a loop, or a function. Multiply this effect for nested blocks, and VB wins for scan-ability in my eyes.

Just putting my two cents out there.